# How to pass CancellationToken to an EventHandler

Tags: c#, async-await, tcplistener, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

Having below reference code for Async TCP server, I want to pass CancellationToken to `OnDataReceived`:

```cs
public sealed class TcpServer : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly TcpListener _listener;
        private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;
        private CancellationToken _token;
        private bool _listening;


        public event EventHandler<ConnectedEventArgs> OnDataReceived;

        public TcpServer(IPAddress address, int port)
        {
            _listener = new TcpListener(address, port);
        }


        public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken? token = null)
        {
            _tokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token ?? new CancellationToken());
            _token = _tokenSource.Token;
            _listener.Start();
            _listening = true;

            try
            {
                while (!_token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    await Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        var tcpClientTask = _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                        var tcpClient = await tcpClientTask;

                        OnDataReceived?.Invoke(tcpClient, new ConnectedEventArgs(tcpClient.GetStream()));
                    }, _token);
                }
            }

            finally
            {
                _listener.Stop();
                _listening = false;
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _tokenSource?.Cancel();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Stop();
        }
    }

    public class ConnectedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public NetworkStream Stream { get; private set; }

        public ConnectedEventArgs(NetworkStream stream)
        {
            Stream = stream;
        }
    }
```

The following code, shows how I am consuming the above code, currently in `ReadStreamBytesAsync` I am passing `new CancellationToken()` instead I want to pass the `token` argument from `MainAsync`:

```cs
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InitAsyncWork();

            Console.WriteLine("ended.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void InitAsyncWork()
        {
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) =>
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                cts.Cancel();
            };
            MainAsync(cts.Token).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        static async Task MainAsync(CancellationToken token)
        {
            using (var server = new TcpServer(IPAddress.Any, 54001))
            {
                server.OnDataReceived += TcpClientOnlyReceive;
                await server.StartAsync(token);
            }
        }

        private static async void TcpClientOnlyReceive(object sender, ConnectedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (TcpClient client = (TcpClient)sender)
                using (NetworkStream stream = e.Stream)
                {
                    while (Utilities.IsTcpClientConnected(client))
                    {
                        if (client.Available == 0)
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(50);
                            continue;
                        }

                        byte[] rawX = await ReadStreamBytesAsync(stream, client.ReceiveBufferSize, new CancellationToken());

                    }//while(client.Connected)

                }//using(client)using(stream)

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Utilities.logger.Error("TcpClientOnlyReceive():Exception!!\r\nMsg: {1}\r\nStack: {2}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        private static async Task<byte[]> ReadStreamBytesAsync(NetworkStream stream, int maxBytesToRead, CancellationToken token)
        {
            var bytesRead = 0;
            var totalBytesRead = 0;
            var clientMsg = new byte[maxBytesToRead];
            byte[] contentBytes;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                do
                {
                    bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(clientMsg, totalBytesRead, clientMsg.Length - totalBytesRead, token);
                    await ms.WriteAsync(clientMsg, totalBytesRead, bytesRead, token);
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                }
                while (bytesRead > 0 && stream.DataAvailable);
                contentBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
            return contentBytes;
        }

    }
```

Should I define `cts` as global variable? Or modify `ConnectedEventArgs` class so that it accept CancellationToken as property ?

**Clarifications:**
Based on the received comments and 1 vote to close the question!

1. My main objective is to close the application once the user press `ctrl+c`, currently that's prevent accepting new connections but it won't cancel the established connections.
2. I never heard of Tasks meant to replace events, if that's true, please share a reference.
3. It will be great to share better version of the code, if its BAD design! *personally I think its clean and robust*.

Comment: Tasks are meant to *replace* event-based programming. Just return the task created by `_listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync()` and let clients await on it. You don't need to call `AcceptTcpClientAsync` inside `Task.Run` because it's already asynchronous.

Comment: Also, the spin-wait in TcpClientOnlyReceive - why? You don't need it.

Comment: It looks like the real question isn't how to pass a CTS to an event (easy, don't use events) but how to "cancel" the `AcceptTcpClientAsync` call, or rather, stop *awaiting* for a connection. The code is similar to several **BAD** answers to similar questions. You can stop listening on a TcpListener by calling Stop. You can use Task.Delay and Task.WhenAll to stop awaiting periodically and check the CTS.

Comment: @Fildor I need `await Task.Delay(50);` because the client keep sending data over mobile network based on trigger, so instead of burning CPU cycles, the spin-wait would give chance for other clients get use of the CPU cycles, isn't?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Currently when I press `Ctrl+c` the TcpServer stops receiving new connections, but the current clients won't exit. so what I need is to stop all clients once the user pressed  `Ctrl+c`. and to do that I need the cancellation token passed to `stream.ReadAsync` and `ms.WriteAsync`. as for your recommendation in the 1st comment, can you modify the code so that I can perform test cases?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos btw: the usage of eventhandler based on reviewed code here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151228/asynchronous-tcp-server I think the usage of `event` helps isolate the tcp client implemntaion from the TcpServer Class, If there is better way, please highlight.

Comment: As other suggested, you should use a task based version for this. But to answer your question: how to pass the cancellationtoken to the eventhandler. Just change the attached event to this and pass the token: server.OnDataReceived += ( sender , e ) => TcpClientOnlyReceive( sender , e , token );

Comment: @Sievajet I ended up adding CancellationToken property to `ConnectedEventArgs`  class and the flow worked. As for task based version, How would you isolate TcpClientOnlyReceive logic from TcpServer class?